# ejecutar accion de boton sin recargar la pagina

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

deseo que me apoyen con una idea resulta que mi sistema hace lo siguiente ejemplo al presionar mi boton que esta en estado verde y en la base de datos su estado es "a" cuando presiono pasa a estado rojo y en la base de datos es "d" y asi sucesivamente pero aqui viene mi dificultad resulta que le he creado un filtro con fechas cuando se abre la pestaña me arroja datos creados ese mismo dia pero al ejecutar el filtro y cambiar las fechas y presionar el boton para cambiar el estado me vuelve a arrojar al dia actual, lo que deseo es hacer que cuando presione el boton me cambie el estado en la base de datos y tambien la apariencia del boton pero me deje con el filtro de fechas que elegi, estoy tratando de resolver pero no encuentro la solucion. Agradecere me brinden una solucion. Acontinuacion mi codigo.

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        include_once '../conexion.php'; 
        include_once 'clases/papeleta.entidad.php';
        include_once 'clases/papeleta.model.php';

       

    if($_SESSION['tipo_usu']=='a' or $_SESSION['tipo_usu']=='d'){
        $titulo='Jefe';
       } else {
        header('location:error.php');
     }


    
        if(!empty($_GET['aprob_jd'])){
            $id=$_GET['aprob_jd'];
            $cans=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM tbpapeleta WHERE aprob_jd='a' and id='$id'");
            if($dat=mysqli_fetch_array($cans)){
                $xSQL="UPDATE tbpapeleta SET aprob_jd='d', u_jd='$nombre' WHERE id='$id'";
                mysqli_query($conexion, $xSQL);                
                header('location:d_papel_comision.php');
            }else{
                $xSQL="UPDATE tbpapeleta SET aprob_jd='a', u_jd='$nombre' WHERE id='$id'";
                mysqli_query($conexion, $xSQL);
                header('location:d_papel_comision.php');
            }
        }

      

        
        $alm = new Papeleta();
        $model = new PapeletaModel();

        if(isset($_REQUEST['action']))
        {
            switch($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
                case 'actualizar':
                    $alm->__SET('id',           $_REQUEST['id']);
                    $alm->__SET('cip',          $_REQUEST['cip']);
                    $alm->__SET('idp',          $_REQUEST['idp']);
                    $alm->__SET('condicion',    $_REQUEST['condicion']);
                    $alm->__SET('fecha',        $_REQUEST['fecha']);
                    $alm->__SET('motivo',       $_REQUEST['motivo']);

                    $model->Actualizar($alm);
                    header('Location: d_papel_comision.php');
                    break;

                case 'registrar':
                    $alm->__SET('cip',          $_REQUEST['cip']);
                    $alm->__SET('idp',          $_REQUEST['idp']);
                    $alm->__SET('condicion',    $_REQUEST['condicion']);
                    $alm->__SET('fecha',        $_REQUEST['fecha']);
                    $alm->__SET('motivo',       $_REQUEST['motivo']);                   

                    $model->Registrar($alm);
                    echo mensajes('La papeleta ha sido registrada con exito!!!','azul');
                    header("refresh: 2; url = d_papel_comision.php");
                    break;

                case 'eliminar':
                    $model->Eliminar($_REQUEST['id']);
                    header('Location: d_papel_comision.php');
                    break;

                case 'editar':
                    $alm = $model->Obtener($_REQUEST['id']);
                    break;
            }
        }    

    if(!empty($_POST['fechai']) or !empty($_POST['fechaf']))
    {
      $fechai=$_POST['fechai'];
      $fechaf=$_POST['fechaf'];      
    }
    else
    {
      $fechai=date('Y-m-d');
      $fechaf=date('Y-m-d');
    }
   
    ?>
     <html lang="es">
     <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
        
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/equipo.ico">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/inicio.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/form-validation.css">
    <link href="../styles/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fontawesone.all.css" type="text/css">
    
    </head>

    <body class="bg-light">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle user-action blanco"><i class="fas fa-user-alt blanco"></i> <span class="blanco"><?php echo $titulo; ?></span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="../d_cambiar.php" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i> Cambiar contraseña</a></a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a href="../cerrar.php" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Salir</a></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample08" aria-controls="navbarsExample08" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarsExample08">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="../d_inicio.php">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="d_asistencia.php">Asistencia</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Reportes</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="d_repor_asistencia.php">Reporte de Asistencia</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="d_repor_faltos.php">Reporte de Faltos</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="d_repor_permisos.php">Reporte de Permisos</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="d_repor_vacaciones.php">Reporte de Vacaciones</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="d_repor_cambios.php">Reporte de Cambio de Guardia</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Papeletas</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="d_papel_permiso.php">Papeleta de Permiso</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="d_papel_comision.php">Papeleta de Comision</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="d_papel_audiencia.php">Papeleta de Audiencia</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="d_papel_vacaciones.php">Papeleta de Vacaciones</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="d_papel_cambio.php">Papeleta de Cambio de Guardia</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="py-sm-5 text-center">
        <h2>Autorizar Papeletas de Comision</h2>
        <p class="lead text-black-10"><?php echo fecha(date('Y-m-d')); ?></p>
    </div>

      <?php $fechaActual = date('Y-m-d'); ?>

    <div align="center">
        <div class="col-md-12 order-md-1 pt-3">
            <form name="form2" action="" method="post" >
                <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-4 mb-1">
                      </div> 
                      <div class="col-md-2 mb-1">
                            <label for="fecha" class="font-weight-bold">Fecha Inicio</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechai" id="fechai" 
                             value="<?php echo $fechai; ?>" required/>
                      </div> 
                      <div class="col-md-2 mb-1">
                             <label for="fecha" class="font-weight-bold">Fecha Final</label>
                             <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechaf" id="fechaf" 
                             value="<?php echo $fechaf; ?>" required/>
                      </div> 
                      <div class="col-md-12 mb-1 pt-2 pb-4" align="center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Verificar papeleta</button>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

        <table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size: 13px;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><strong>#</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><strong>Cip</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><strong>Grado Nombres y Apellidos</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><strong>Condicion</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><strong>Taller</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><strong>Dia</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><strong>Motivo</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><strong>F.Registro</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>J. Taller</strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>J. Dpto.</strong></td>     
                <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>Eliminar</strong></td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
        
            <?php
            
            $contador=0;

           
             if(!empty($_POST['fechai']) or !empty($_POST['fechaf']))
             {
                
                $consulta="SELECT t.id, t.cip, CONCAT_WS(' ',p.grado, p.nombre, p.apellidos) as completo, t.condicion, ta.abreviatura as taller, t.fecha, t.motivo, t.fecha_reg_trip, DATE_FORMAT(t.fecha_reg_trip,'%Y-%m-%d') as fRegistro, t.aprob_jt, t.aprob_jd, t.aprob_ma,t.aprob_jp FROM tbpapeleta as t INNER JOIN tbpersonal as p ON p.id=t.idp INNER JOIN tbtaller as ta ON ta.id = p.taller WHERE (ta.id = 1 OR ta.id = 2 OR ta.id = 3 OR ta.id = 5 OR ta.id = 6 OR ta.id = 7 OR ta.id = 8 OR ta.id = 9) AND t.aprob_jt='a' AND t.condicion='COMISION' AND DATE_FORMAT(t.fecha_reg_trip,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$fechai' AND '$fechaf'";
             }
            else
            {
              $consulta="SELECT t.id, t.cip, CONCAT_WS(' ',p.grado, p.nombre, p.apellidos) as completo, t.condicion,  ta.abreviatura as taller, t.fecha, t.motivo, t.fecha_reg_trip, DATE_FORMAT(t.fecha_reg_trip,'%Y-%m-%d') as fRegistro, t.aprob_jt, t.aprob_jd, t.aprob_ma,t.aprob_jp FROM tbpapeleta as t INNER JOIN tbpersonal as p ON p.id=t.idp INNER JOIN tbtaller as ta ON ta.id = p.taller WHERE (ta.id = 1 OR ta.id = 2 OR ta.id = 3 OR ta.id = 5 OR ta.id = 6 OR ta.id = 7 OR ta.id = 8 OR ta.id = 9) AND t.aprob_jt='a' AND t.condicion='COMISION' AND DATE_FORMAT(t.fecha_reg_trip,'%Y-%m-%d') ='$fechaActual'";
            }

            $sql=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);               
                
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
              $contador++;
                    
                    
            ?>
             <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $contador; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['cip']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['completo']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['condicion']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['taller']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['fecha']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['motivo']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $row['fecha_reg_trip']; ?></td>
                <td class="text-center"><?php echo aprobacion($row['aprob_jt']); ?></td>
                
              //AQUI EL BOTON LA FUNCION APROBACION LE DA LA FORMA DE BOTON.
                <td class="text-center">
                  <a href="d_papel_comision.php?aprob_jd=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo aprobacion($row['aprob_jd']); ?></a>
                </td>
              
                
              </tr>
            <?php } ?> 
            </tbody>
          
        </table>



<script src="../js/form-validation.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Daniel, investiga un poco sobre peticiones ajax y la forma en que se usan, es más o menos lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

El boton debería ser asi

```
<a href="#" onclick="enviar(<?php echo $row['id']?>);"></a>
```

Y la funcion algo asi

```
function enviar(id){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "d_papel_comision.php",
    data: "aprob_jd="+ id,
    })
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Jose Mariano pero resulta que al ejecutar el codigo si me cambia en la base datos pero en la tabla no me actualiza, me sigue poniendo el boton en verde :(

Comment: Un gran servicio alguien me puede ayudar con este codigo ya que lo implemente pero cuando presiono el boton no me actualiza el estado.